# laravel eloquent : How to update data if exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a table where i have `user_id` and `role_id` in it. Now if I select user_id =1 from dropdown and role_id = 2 from dropdown and save it ..Next time if I want to set same user another role instead of creating new row in table..How to update it without creating new one? can anyone suggest something?

```
$roleUser = RoleUser::firstOrNew(
            ['role_id' => $request->Input(['role_id']),
             'user_id' =>$request->Input(['user_id'])] );
            $roleUser->save();
```

I used the firstOrNew method but it creates a new entry instead of updating the old one.

Comment: So a `User` can only have 1 `Role`??

Comment: Yes .. User have only one role

Comment: Why do you use a pivot table if a user can only have one role?

Comment: Are there any other columns in your `RoleUser` table other than `user_id` and `role_id`?

Answer (score 3):

I'm using this source code when Update or Create new record. Worked well with Laravel 5.2

If exist one record have `user_id` == your `user_id` => Will update `role_id`

Else will insert one more record for your `user_id`

```
$roleUser = RoleUser::updateOrCreate([
    'user_id' => $request['user_id'],
    ], 
    [
        'role_id' => $request['role_id'],
    ]);
```

Comment: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: update `role_user` set `role_id` = 2 where `id` is null` I got this error..after I used your solution

Comment: @Hola Your table don't have `id` column?

Comment: @Hola I guess you using ZizacoEntrust Role?

Comment: No i tried to make my own authorization concept .. Yes in RoleUser Model I have only user_id and role_id no other column.

Comment: @Hola So please try add one more column `increments('id');`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code that should work. However, I don't quite understand your database architecture choice. If a user can only have one role, why don't you define a `role_id` in your `users` table, and then use a `belongsTo`  relationship?

```
$role_user = RoleUser::where('role_id',$request->get('role_id'))
    ->where('user_id',$request->get('user_id'))
    ->first();

if (is_null($role_user)) {
    RoleUser::create([
        'user_id' => $request->get('user_id'),
        'role_id' => $request->get('role_id')
    ])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

so where's the issue here?

you are using `firstOrNew` method , which is similar to `firstOrCreate` typically do the following:

- Select from the database
- and if not exists
- insert the given data
- in case of using firstOrNew , you will need to `->save()` to execute the query .

so it will not update your data if exists .

however, I think that you are looking for [`updateOrCreate`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent) method, which is take two array arguments , the first is the inserted data , and if exists the function takes the two array argument to update your row.

> You may also come across situations where you want to update an
>   existing model or create a new model if none exists. Laravel provides
>   an updateOrCreate method to do this in one step. Like the
>   firstOrCreate method, updateOrCreate persists the model, so there's no
>   need to call save():

```
$roleUser = RoleUser::updateOrCreate(
    // if not exists, insert the following RoleUser data
    ['role_id' => $request->Input(['role_id']),'user_id' =>$request->Input(['user_id'])],
    // otherwise, update RoleUser set role_id = ?
    ['role_id' => $request->Input(['role_id'])]
);
```

Comment: See the situation is if i choose a user as admin next time if i choose the same user as user it should update admin to user not creating a new row in table.may be you don't like my logic but I want to use this one.so your case if a user selected as admin and next time the same user choose as user in database it will have admin as well as user role .

Comment: checkout your `RoleUser` relation rules, or add where clause to your query to specify the `user_id`;

Answer (score 0):

`$roleUser = RoleUser::firstOrNew(array('role_id' => Input::get('role_id')));
 $roleUser ->save();`

you can add multiple fields..

example..

If there's a flight from Oakland to San Diego, set the price to $99.
If no matching model exists, create one.

`$flight = App\Flight::updateOrCreate(
    ['departure' => 'Oakland', 'destination' => 'San Diego'],
    ['price' => 99]
);`
`